# Python get N characters from string with specific substring

Tags: python, string

I have a very long string that I extracted from a image file.
The string can look like this

`...\n\nDate: 01.01.2022\n\nArticle-no: 123456789\n\nArticle description: asdfqwer 1234...\n...`

How do I extract just the 10 characters after the substring `"Article-no:"`?

I tried solving it with a different approach using rfind like this but it tends to fail every now and then if the start and end string is not accurate.

```
    s = "... string shown above ..."
    start = "Article-no: "
    end = "Article description: "
    print(s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `split`:

```
string.split("Article-no: ", 1)[1][0:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) might come in very handy.

```py
import re

# Create a pattern which matches "Article-no: " literally,
# and then grabs the digits that follow.
pattern = re.compile(r"Article-no: (\d+)")
s = "...\n\nDate: 01.01.2022\n\nArticle-no: 123456789\n\nArticle description: asdfqwer 1234...\n..."

match = pattern.search(s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

This outputs:

```
123456789
```

The regular expression used is `Article-no: (\d+)`, which has the following parts:

```
Article-no:      # Match this text literally
(                # Open a new group (i.e. group 1)
\d+              # Match 1 or more occurrences of a digit
)                # Close group 1
```

The `re` module will search the string for places where this matches, and then you can extract the digit from the matches.